# validate string made up of numbers only separated by whitespace

Tags: java, regex

I have a String which can only have integers separated by whitespace. For example:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
9 8 7
1 p 3 // it should not pass
```

So my string should always have numbers in it separated by whitespace so that's why I added this regex check to validate the string but it's not working:

```
String line = "1 2 3"; // "1 p 3"
if(!line.matches("[ ]?\\d+")) {
    //it should come here for "1 p 3" string
}
```

What's wrong with my regex here?

Comment: did you try `^[0-9|' ']*$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.matches` will only evaluate to `true` if the *whole* string matches the regular expression. (you could think of it as being implicitly surrounded by `^` and `$`.) So, to validate a string with only numbers with whitespace between, use:

```
\d+(?: \d+)*
```

https://regex101.com/r/wK9WhP/1

Note that there's no need for a character set with only a single character in it - easier to leave out the character set entirely.

```
String line = "1 2 3"; // "1 p 3"
if(line.matches("\\d+(?: \\d+)*")) {
    System.out.println("match");
} else {
    System.out.println("no match");
}
```